# Environmental variables and folder locations - Docker & Git Bash

Tags: docker, git-bash

I am trying to run a docker container (https://metriql.com/metriql-cli/cli-overview/ using Git Bash on Windows:

```
export DBT_PROJECT_DIR=${PWD};
export DBT_PROFILES_DIR=${HOME}/.dbt;
export METRIQL_PORT=5656;

docker run -it -p "${METRIQL_PORT}:5656" -v "${DBT_PROJECT_DIR}:/root/app" -v "${DBT_PROFILES_DIR}:/root/.dbt" -e METRIQL_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0 -e DBT_PROJECT_DIR=/root/app buremba/metriql serve
```

However, I was getting the error ' profiles.yml does not exist in /C:/Users/katep/.dbt/profiles.yml. Please set --profiles-dir option.'

So, I changed to:

```
export DBT_PROJECT_DIR=${PWD};
export DBT_PROFILES_DIR=${HOME}/.dbt;
export METRIQL_PORT=5656;

docker run -p "${METRIQL_PORT}:5656" -v "${DBT_PROJECT_DIR}:/root/app" -v "${DBT_PROFILES_DIR}:/root/.dbt" -e METRIQL_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0 -e DBT_PROJECT_DIR=/root/app buremba/metriql serve --project-dir "C:/Users/katep/OneDrive/Documents/redshift/metriql" --profiles-dir "C:/Users/katep/.dbt/"
 --manifest-json file:C:/Users/katep/OneDrive/Documents/redshift/metriql/target/manifest.json
```

I continue getting the same error. My assumption is that I am assigning environmental variables incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. The correct command is:

```
docker run -it -p "${METRIQL_PORT}:5656" -v "/${DBT_PROJECT_DIR}://root/app" -v "/${DBT_PROFILES_DIR}://root/dbt" -e METRIQL_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0 -e DBT_PROJECT_DIR=//root/app buremba/metriql serve
```